# Different typeerror and Chrome and IE 11

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code which works in Chrome.

```
$.getJSON("mydata.js", function(data){
    var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
      $("div").append(field + " ");
    });
  });
```

In IE, I get this error:

> TypeError: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

And when I change the code tho this:

```
$.getJSON("mydata.js", function(result){
        var t = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(t, function(i, field){
          $("div").append(field + " ");
        });
      });
```

It works in IE 11 and in Chrome I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like IE 11 is returning a string and Chrome is returning an object. For the time being I am checking if the returned result is an object, if it is not I convert it into an object as follows:

```
if (typeof data != "object") { data = JSON.parse(data); }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getJSON` *already* parses the JSON into an object (or array, or whatever it is) before it invokes the callback. Remove the `JSON` parts from your code, and use the `data` without modification:

```
$.getJSON("mydata.js", function(data){
  $.each(data, function(i, field) {
    $("div").append(field + " ");
  });
});
```

If you try to parse data that's already been parsed, errors will likely arise.

Comment: In Chrome, it works but in IE 11, I get this error: TypeError: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected